# Many to Many prepared query

Tags: ormlite

I am using ORMLite and I have this models (I have omitted id fields and visibility for readability):

```
class Book {
    String title;
    List<Author> authors;
}

class Author {
    String name;
    List<Book> books;
}

class BookAuthor {
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Author author;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Book book;
}
```

I want a query with all books order_by title and with their authors in their list, so I have this methods, the first to resolve many-to-many and then to get books shorted:

```
 private PreparedQuery<Author> makeAuthorsForBookQuery() throws SQLException {

        QueryBuilder<BookAuthor, Integer> bookAuthorQb = bookAuthorDao.queryBuilder();
        bookAuthorQb.selectColumns("author");
        SelectArg userSelectArg = new SelectArg();
        bookAuthorQb.where().eq("", userSelectArg);

        QueryBuilder<Author, String> authorQb = authorDao.queryBuilder();
        authorQb.where().in("name", bookAuthorQb);

        return authorQb.prepare();
    }

private PreparedQuery<Book> makeBooksQuery() throws SQLException {
        QueryBuilder<Book,Integer> bookQb = bookDao.queryBuilder();
        bookDao.orderBy(Manga.TITLE_COLUMN_NAME, true);
        return bookDao.prepare();
```

But if I do to this way then I have to iterate over each book and to fire the AutorsForBookQuery and assign the result to the book list.

My question is: **Does exist any other way to get this**? I mean, something as to do an inner-join where map the authors in the books automagically and save it as a PreparedQuery?

PD: My goal is to load this prepared query in a CloseableIterator

Answer (score 0):

> I want a query with all books order_by title and with their authors in their list...

What I would do @Fran is to do 2 queries.  One for `Book`s ordered by title.  Then another query for the authors joined with the `BookAuthor` class with book.id in the list of books you got.  So it is 2 queries but then it is not another query by `Book`.

ORMLite isn't helping you much there for sure.